# The Append statement keep on executing every time

Tags: jquery

the alert keep on  appending every time instead i want it to append only once

This is what my whole code look like, still learning things !

```
// 1. listen for submit 
jQuery('.save').submit(function(event) {

    // 2.  get the form data
    var formData = {
        'editor_content' : jQuery('.jqte_editor').text()
    };
    // grab the form url
    url = jQuery('.save').attr('action');

     //  Show spinner as request start
    $('.spinner').show();

    //  4. process the form

    jQuery.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : url, // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                     encode          : true
    })
        // using the success promise callback
        .success(function(data) {
            // stop spinner as request completes
                    $('.spinner').hide();

            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
            if(! data.success)
            {
```

// this keep on appending every time i press the submit button

```
                $('.save').append('<div class="warning alert">'+data.editor_content+'</div>');
            }
            });

    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Where do you set `data.success`?

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify if the `.alert` box has been already added and prevent adding it again..

```
if(!data.success && $('.save > .warning.alert').size() == 0){
   $('.save').append('<div class="warning alert">'+data.editor_content+'</div>');
}
```

Comment: ...assuming there's nothing else in the `.save` element. Might be better to check if an `.save > .warning.alert` element already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
var warned = false;
if (! data.success){
    if (! warned)
       $('.save').append('<div class="warning alert">' + data.editor_content + '</div>');
       warned = true;
    }
}
```